# Can you interleave a tf.data dataset from multiple files?

Tags: generator, tensorflow2.0, interleave, tf.data.dataset

I currently have a dataset that is split into three different npy file types: one containing all the x vars that are floats, one containing all the x vars that are ints, and one containing all the y-labels.

To loop through all the files, I created a tf.data dataset from a generator like so

```
def tf_data_generator(filelist_float, filelist_int, filelist_y, batch_size=4096):
    i=0
    while True:
        if i == len(filelist_y):
            i = 0
            indicies = np.arange(len(filelist_float))
            np.random.shuffle(indicies)
            filelist_float
        else:
            xf = np.load(filelist_float[i])
            xi = np.load(filelist_int[i])
            y = np.load(filelist_y[i])
            filefinish = False
            fileIndex = 0
            # In case files have different lengths
            fileEnd = np.min([xf.shape[0], xi.shape[0], y.shape[0]])
            while not filefinish:
                if fileIndex + batch_size >= fileEnd:
                    yield np.concatenate((xf[fileIndex:fileEnd], xi[fileIndex:fileEnd]), axis=1), y[fileIndex:fileEnd]
                    filefinish = True
                else:
                    yield np.concatenate((xf[fileIndex:fileIndex+batch_size], xi[fileIndex:fileIndex+batch_size]), axis=1), y[fileIndex:fileIndex+batch_size]
                    fileIndex += batch_size
            i+=1

 training_generator = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(tf_data_generator, args = training_files_dir, output_types = (tf.float16, tf.int16))
```

My question is whether it would be faster if to interleave this process instead, and if so, could I do that with these three separate files or would I have to append them all into one? One thing to note is that the each npy file can be loadable into memory but there will be over 10,000 npy files so I can't load all the files into memory.

Thanks in advance for any ideas!

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, yes you definitely can. If anyone is curious or gets stuck, here is my TF2

In the **call** function, the generator receives just one of the X_float_input files, and uses that to find the corresponding X_int_input and Y_input files.

```
class generator:
    def __call__(self, file, batch_size): #X_float_input.npy
        actual_file = file.decode("utf-8") 
        xf = np.load(actual_file)
        xi = np.load(actual_file.replace("float", "int"))
        y = np.load(actual_file.replace("X_float", "Y"))

        filefinish = False
        fileIndex = 0
        # In case files have different lengths
        fileEnd = np.min([xf.shape[0], xi.shape[0], y.shape[0]])
        while not filefinish:
            if fileIndex + batch_size >= fileEnd:
                yield np.concatenate((xf[fileIndex:fileEnd], xi[fileIndex:fileEnd]), axis=1), y[fileIndex:fileEnd]
                filefinish = True
            else:
                yield np.concatenate((xf[fileIndex:fileIndex+batch_size], xi[fileIndex:fileIndex+batch_size]), axis=1), y[fileIndex:fileIndex+batch_size]
                fileIndex += batch_size

# training_files_dir = ["X_float_input_1.npy", "X_float_input_2.npy"]
training_generator = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(training_files_dir)
training_generator = training_generator.interleave(lambda filename: tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
            generator(), 
            output_types=(tf.float16, tf.int16),
            args=(filename, BATCH_SIZE,)), num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE).prefetch(tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
training_generator = training_generator.shuffle(10000, reshuffle_each_iteration=True).repeat(EPOCHS)#.prefetch(tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE).cache()
```

One thing to note though, is that you need to call the repeat function with the number of epochs otherwise the generator won't update.